# python: ошибка с методом del

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Я тестирую функцию поиска строки и работу с этой строкой в файле, мне нужно удалить эту строку после работы с ней, мой код:

```
import bonus
file = open('c://testper/bonus.py', 'r')
qwe = file.readlines()
print(qwe)
if '\n1' in qwe:
    print('Sucs!(1)')
    del '\n1'
else:
    print('error')
```

В файле bonus.py:

```
2
1
3
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "c://testper/test.py", line 7
    del '\n1'
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot delete literal
```

Погуглил и всё равно не смог решить проблему, помогите кто сможет! Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй открыть файл в режиме "r+", мне кажется что ты пытаешься изменить файл при этом открыв его в режиме чтения, а ещё 1 2 3 в bonus.py надо запихнуть в список
Код:

```py
from bonus import i
file = open('c://testper/bonus.py', 'r')
qwe = file.readlines()
print(qwe)
if '1' in qwe:
    print('Sucs!(1)')
    del i[0]
else:
    print('error')
```

bonus.py :

```py
i = [1, 2, 3]
```

Я слегка не понимаю что вы хотели сделать с файлом bonus.py, поэтому вставьте вместо '1' то что вам надо

Comment: Сделал как вы ответили, не помогло(

Comment: Файл действительно нужно открыть в режиме `r+`, но это неполный ответ.

Comment: Сделал также как написано, Теперь он выводит error ( print('error') )

Answer (score 2):

Инструкция `del` принимает имя переменной

https://pythonz.net/references/named/del/

Upd: Попробуйте вместо `del '\n1'` так:

```
del qwe[qwe.index('\n1')]
```

Comment: Сделал так: del qwe[1]. Он все равно не удаляется, но ошибка исчезла

Comment: Теперь Вы пытаетесь удалить элемент по **индексу** 1. Почитайте документацию

Comment: yourUpd: выходит error и строка не удаляется

Comment: @str, ну так если у Вас выводится **error**, то это значит, что не выполняется условие `if`. Проверьте, как у Вас считывается файл. Может, стоит вывести содержимое `qwe` на экран (посмотрите, что там)?

Comment: **qwe** вывел на экран, там: ['2\n', '1\n', '3']

Comment: Теперь разве не очевидно? Вы ищете элемент '\n1', а у Вас - '1\n'